# Folder permissions, red x on user object

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

On shared folders on the file server, for the domain user name object under the security tab, the icon has a red x.

There are no symptoms, the users have full access, there is just a red x on the icon for their name.

[image: dialog box with error]

Why is this?

For clarification, logged into the windows 2008 r2 file server, browse to a users shared folder, right click on the folder, hit properties, click the security tab. The object representing the users domain name has a little red x on the lower right hand corner of the icon that looks like a single man. There are no symptoms beyond me wondering why the red x is there.

update: it does not show the x when you look at permissions from a workstation, only on the file server

Comment: domain groups do not have the x, only the individual user

Comment: the user has no issues reading, writing, or modifying his share, and it is the same for the other shares and other users.

Comment: Found out what was causing it, the server was part of a workgroup and I joined it to our domain. As I added users to the domain I disabled their local accounts, but did not remove them. I am guessing that because the local username was the same as the domain username(just a different UPN suffix), it was showing the disabled user icon. Once I removed the local user account completely, the red x went away on the domain account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out what was causing it, the server was part of a workgroup and I joined it to our domain. As I added users to the domain I disabled their local accounts, but did not remove them. I am guessing that because the local username was the same as the domain username(just a different UPN suffix), it was showing the disabled user icon. Once I removed the local user account completely, the red x went away on the domain account.

Comment: The icon for the domain account will also change back if you re-enable the local account. But the change will only occur either way if you log out and log back in.

Comment: I was going to comment that what you were describing sounded like a disabled user account but when you said that the user still had access I got thrown for a loop. I didn't even consider a local user account. Thanks for posting the solution.